# numpy polyfit with data that has varying levels of statistical significance

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

Polyfit is a great tool to fit a line to a set of points.  However my data has varying levels of statistical significance.

For example, for one point (x1,y2) I might only have 10 observations, while for another point (x2,y2) I might have 10,000 observations.  I usually have at least 10 points and I'd like to weight each according to statistical significance when using polyfit.  Is there any way (or a similar function) that allows for that?

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to use weighted least squares in [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.WLS.html?highlight=wls#statsmodels-regression-linear-model-wls)

roughly:

y is response or endogenous variable (`endog`)

x is your 1 dimensional explanatory variable

w your weight array, the higher the more weight on that observation

to get the polynomial matrix, and fit

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
exog = np.vander(x, degree+1)
result = sm.WLS(y, exog, weight=w).fit()
```

the parameters are in `result.params`. The fitted values are in `result.fittedvalues`

Prediction has changed between versions. With version 0.4 you can use

```
result.predict(np.vander(x_new, degree+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

more straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x,y,deg,w=weight of each observation)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about numpy but you can write your own polyfit function. Polyfit is just solving of linear equation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates
  (in your case epsilon is probably 0)

You can see that all you have to do is multipling each line in y and each line in x whit your coeficient.
This shoul be like 10 lines of code (i remeber that it took me like 4h to reinvent minsquare equation on my own, but only 2 lines of code in MATLAB)